# LVM and partition recovery

Tags: linux, partition, lvm, data-recovery

I'm new here and i need your help.
A tried to search similar question but I not found.

I've lost LVM e patition table on HD with 2Tb capacity and I need to restore it.
Hard disk is not damaged, only have unallocated space :-(
I've very importand data into it :(
please help me. Resut of gpart below

```
root@debian:~# sudo gpart /dev/sdb

Begin scan...
Possible partition(Linux LVM2 physical volume), size(1428531mb), offset(2250mb)
Possible partition(Linux LVM2 physical volume), size(476929mb), offset(1430781mb)
End scan.

Checking partitions...

* Warning: partition(Linux LVM physical volume) starts beyond disk end.

* Warning: partition(Linux LVM physical volume) starts beyond disk end.
Partition(Linux LVM physical volume): invalid primary
Partition(Linux LVM physical volume): invalid primary
Ok.

Guessed primary partition table:
Primary partition(1)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(2)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(3)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r

Primary partition(4)
   type: 000(0x00)(unused)
   size: 0mb #s(0) s(0-0)
   chs:  (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)d (0/0/0)-(0/0/0)r
```

I didn't know it was enough to edit the main question. I'm sorry.
I am absolutely sure that I am using RAID1. The NAS was equipped with 2 2T disks and the total space available was 2T.
The NAS is a Netgear RND2000 (ReadyNAS Duo), I can't tell you if v1 or v2 and I'm sorry but it broke so I can't even tell you the firmware version. This disk was Disc 2 on NAS.

At at 99% the NAS damaged could be identical to this one (this however mounts 2 discs of 1T instead of 2T)

[image]

mmm...... X-RAID ? mumble mubmle...

Guys ... problem solved. I have another NAS that has 2 1T HDs (the one I posted photos of). Before modifying or touching the partitions of the HD that gives me problems, I tried to remove the two 1T HDs from the working NAS and I installed in the right slot only the 2T one that I can't read.
Magically all the data has appeared, so now I immediately copy everything.
I was lucky that I have 2 identical NAS, but what else would I have done? They are also very old.

p.s. I don't know how to mark the solved post

Comment: The sizes found look compatible with what you're looking for, but the warning about beyond disk end not. Is your disk really seen (not assumed to be but detected) as a 2TB sized disk?

Comment: https://www.suse.com/c/recovering-lost-lvm-volume-disk/ google is useful.  that has several recovery options, it's a long article. Speaking for myself, if I have important data, I'm not going to put it on LVM volume running some type of software raid with a partition ontop of it, I'd use mdraid direct, or zfs or best, hardware raid with a single partition, ext4. The more layers you have, the harder it is to recover from failures. A guy I know makes a living recovering data from failed LVM setups....

Comment: I will read well the link you passed me, today I have read so many probably that I have escaped.
You're right about LVM, but it did all the nas netgear, I didn't choose to use it.
Now I have bought a qnap ts-431xeu, but I need to recover the data

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply. Yes it is, 2TB confirmed, not supposed.
Follow result of test disk scan

```
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org
TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
http://www.cgsecurity.org

Disk /dev/sdb - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63

The harddisk (2000 GB / 1863 GiB) seems too small! (< 3189 GB / 2970 GiB)
Check the harddisk size: HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection...

The following partition can't be recovered:
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>  FAT16 >32M           365639 248 31 387773 154  1  355576759


[ Continue ]
182 GB / 169 GiB
```

This hd was part of a nas that got damaged. It was 2 disks in RAID1.
The other disk is damaged like the nas hardware, this one seems to have no faults but it is completely unallocated

Comment: Are you **absolutely sure** the RAID mode was RAID1 and not something else? The fact that the partition table seems to be for a much bigger disk suggests this might be the partition table on a first stripe of a RAID0 set. The second stripe of the RAID0 set would then be at the very beginning of the other disk, and might not contain no partition table at all, making the disk seem completely unallocated. Or if it was a JBOD set, the space of the second disk would have been simply appended to the end of the first one, and the partition table on the 1st disk would apply to the entire 2-disk set.

Comment: Since the disks were from a NAS device, you should **edit your question** to include the model of the NAS device and its system firmware version number, and any other information requested by commenters. You should use neither the "add comment" nor "post your answer" for additional information, as StackExchange works a bit differently from discussion groups you may be used to. Any Answer posts that aren't actually answering the question will get flagged for deletion.